Back button changes from cancel to save and exit
I'm working on a campaign management tool, and the user can create a new campaign which takes them to the creation page (a full page takeover). This full page takeover has a save and exit button on the top left of the page. But when a user has not entered anything in the input fields, the save and exit is not a save and exit because you are not saving anything and nothing is created.
A thought is to have that save and exit button say "cancel" when the user first hits the page, but after entering some info, the button then changes to "save and exit" and the user can save any progress.
I'm not sure that that is the correct way to go about doing things, as I would've thought changing the button naming is a not a good idea, but I am curious to hear other peoples thoughts and if agreed, how could we solve the initial problem.

When you land on a new page, you can see it in another perspective.
Why do you want to have save trigger that will save and exit the page? You have multiple advantages if you keep the two separate.
User can fill the info asked for and save gets enabled. At any time once users saves it, if user wanted to modify anything you are forcefully taking user away from the interaction point.
Retaining the user attention on the same page not only ensures no surprises but also gives user a chance to consciously move away from the page by clicking on Exit.
You can have save & Exit kept separately.
Also, any particular reason for having these CTAs top left of the page?
